# OpenCV - Error when drawing line or rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, drawing

I'm getting an error when trying to run the following code and have no idea why.  This is essentially the exact same code that's used in the tutorials.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cv_trackbar2.py", line 41, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.5+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206)     Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

And the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

# Draw a green rectangle
img = cv2.rectangle(img,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)

while (True):

    cv2.imshow('draw',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle) you can tell that the function `cv2.rectangle` returns `void`. So the problem is that you are assigning the return value (which is `None`) to `img`.

Do this instead

```
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

# Draw a green rectangle
cv2.rectangle(img,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)

while (True):

    cv2.imshow('draw',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just following the tutorials so I figured their stuff would be correct.